# PostgreSQL Insert into table A and table B if table A does not contain the value

Tags: postgresql, syntax, insert

Hi I am trying to do the following in a postgreSql table but am having trouble with the syntax.

Psuedocode:

```
if (tableA.column1 does not contain value1)
{
    INSERT INTO tableA (column1, column2)
    VALUES value1, value2
}

// do this check even if the above already existed
if (tableB does not contain value1 and value3 in the same row)
{
    // it is ok if value1 and value3 already exist in the table, just not the same row
    INSERT INTO tableB (column1, column2)
    VALUES (value1, value3)
}

return true
```

Any help with the actual syntax for this operation would be much appreciated!

Comment: I don't see how the first and the second condition "belong" together. You can simply run both independently from each other.

Comment: interesting, now that i look at it, you make a good point!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
-- first insert:
insert into tablea (col1, col2)
select 1,2
from tablea
where not exists (select * from tablea where col1 = 1);

-- second insert (same logic to apply a conditional insert)
insert into tableb (col1, col2)
select 1,2
from tableb
where not exists (select * from tableb where col1 = 1 and col2 = 2);
```

Comment: Just remember to `LOCK` the tables or be prepared to handle errors (if unique) or duplicates (if not unique) due to multiple transactions concurrently checking and inserting the same record.

Comment: @CraigRinger: why locking? Isn't simply wrapping into one transaction enough?

Comment: @mvp If you know nobody else will be concurrently `insert`ing, yes. But if you know that you know it won't cost you anything to lock either. Inserts don't block each other. If there's a unique key shared between two concurrent inserts then *both* will `SELECT` and see the key doesn't exist then both will try to insert it. One will win, the other will fail to commit with a duplicate key error despite not being able to see the conflicting row. If there *isn't* a unique key then visibility rules will result in neither seeing the row the other is inserting and two rows getting inserted.